# passing data between injectables in angular2

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

The question is self explanatory, I have seen that since the @Injectables are not components, I cannot use the traditional @Input and @Output to get this job done. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: why you cannot use? What is that you are looking for ? Read this [**asking help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask.

Comment: You can inject one service into another. The rest is self explanatory ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can inject one injectable into second injectable via constructor:

```
import { SecureHttp } from './secureHttp.service';

@Injectable()
export class IdentityService {

  constructor(private http: SecureHttp) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful :)